# Execute a php script and display the result on the same page

Tags: php, file, upload

I am writing a page where it allows user to upload a file into my remote database.

So when the user has successfully uploaded the file, my label will display "File Uploaded Successfully".

If the file is not of the type that my server accepts, the label will display "Incorrect file format.  Please try again."

Is it possible?

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="/LS/import_export.html">

<div class="form-group">

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="75">
<label for="file">PHP Code here?</label>

</div>

<button type="submit" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Don't give the action in form and instead of submit use button and JS function on the click of it

Comment: I suggest you use <input type="submit" instead of button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for you to just get started with the basics.

```
 <?php
    if( isset($_FILES["file"]) and $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
        /* Do your validation here
            Reference URL
            http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
        */

        if($move_file){
            $status = "File Uploaded Successfully";
        } else {
            $status = "Incorrect file format. Please try again.";
        }
    }
    ?>

<form method="post" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="75">
  <label for="file">PHP Code here?</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will want to check the

```
$_FILES['file']['type']
```

of your upload which you can compare to an array of exceptable file formats, something like

```
$aExceptedFormats = array('image/jpg', 'image/png');
if (!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $aExceptedFormats)) {
    echo "Incorrect file format. Please try again.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict used by using HTML5 accept attribute :

```
<input type="file" name="my-image" id="image" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
```

OR using PHP

```
$approved_types = array("image/png","image/jpg","image/jpeg");
$approved_exts = array("png","jpg","jpeg");
if (!in_array($_FILES['new_image']['type'], $approved_types)) {
   die("Wrong type of file submitted press use your back button and try again.");
   }
```

Refernece : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148485-restricting-file-types-and-size-in-upload-form/

Answer (score 0):

Change your action attribute to blank or use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Place your `POST` action before your form.

*Note: use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for file uploads*

eg.

```
if(isset($_POST['Import'])){
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
}

<form method="post" role="form" action="/LS/import_export.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="75">
<label for="file">PHP Code here?</label>

</div>

<input type="submit" name="Import" value="Upload" /> 

</form>
```

For a reference about PHP upload. You may check it [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('database', $con);
            if($db)
                 {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO upload(u_name,name,size,type,content) VALUES (specific values ...)";
                    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
                    mysql_close();
                    echo "<ul class='testimonials'>
                            <li>
                            <blockquote>
                                <center><span style='color: green;'>File Uploaded Successfully</span></center>
                            </blockquote>
                            </li>
                          </ul>";
                }
                else 
                { 
                    echo "<ul class='testimonials'>
                            <li>
                            <blockquote>
                                <center>span style='color: red;'>File Uploading Failed</span></center>
                            </blockquote>
                            </li>
                          </ul>"; 
                }
            }
```

you can try this..